# "Тут было тщательно накрыто" - глагол (причастие) самодостаточен?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Крылечко входа почти тотчас превращалось в длинную крытую веранду, и
>   вся полутьма её узкого помещения, больше похожего на коридор, была
>   уставлена столами и стульями. **Тут было тщательно накрыто**, кругом
>   белели крахмальные скатерти, поблёскивала сервировка, **словно всё
>   было готово для какого-то призрачного бала**.

А бал с сервировкой коррелирует, о?

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: “Тут было тщательно накрыто”_ === А почему Вас смущает эта часть предложения? По-моему, здесь-то всё нормально, а вот использование двух "было" ("тут было", "всё было") несколько напрягает... Как вариант (с минимальной корректировкой): _Тут было тщательно накрыто, кругом белели крахмальные скатерти, поблёскивала сервировка — словно в преддверии (в ожидании?) какого-то призрачного бала._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом выражении не видно ничего плохого: подразумевается "(накрыто) *кем-то*" - есть реальный производитель действия, которого в этом действии и характеризует "тщательность". Вот если бы "(незнамо что) *тщательно накрылось*", были бы сомнения. Перед последним оборотом я бы поставил тире, поскольку он косвенно (без явного глагольного управления) "итожит" всё перечисленное.

Answer (score 1):

Крылечко входа почти тотчас превращалось в длинную крытую веранду, и вся полутьма её узкого помещения, больше похожего на коридор, была уставлена столами и стульями. Тут было тщательно ***накрыто***, кругом белели крахмальные скатерти, поблёскивала сервировка, **словно  всё готовилось для какого-то призрачного (непонятного, но торжественного) церемониала.**

1) Тут было тщательно ***накрыто*** — обычно используются выражения ***накрыть стол, накрыто на стол,*** а здесь безличная форма и даже без стола. Поэтому можно использовать курсив (вместо кавычек) для не совсем обычного употребления слова.

2) Неясно, **о каком бале идет речь** (не хватает контекста), с сервировкой бал не очень сочетается (что-то желательно добавить или изменить).

Comment: _Накрыть стол_ (или "_на_ стол" - есть такое и у Ожегова) подходит в случае одного стола, напр. в домашних условиях. В остальных случаях "стол" обычно не упоминается (хотя возможно "накрыть столы"; "накрыть на столы" вообще не говорят), от чего выражение становится более идиоматичным (скатерти, которой "накрывают стол" может не быть вообще; подразумеваются блюда и приборы): накрыть/накрыто на столько-то персон в таком-то помещении для кого-то - в результате не возникает ничего плохого от перехода к безличной форме.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример  литературного текста, где используется безличная форма? Мне это выражение, как и нашему редактору,  не кажется самодостаточным.

Comment: Первое попавшееся (не выбирал - слишком много):
_В пиршественной зале было накрыто для дружинников с отдельно стоящим столом для их командиров и приближенных Игоря._ (Борис Васильев, "Весь Васильев", 2019)
_Около двухъ часовъ, когда было накрыто на столъ, къ нашему дому подкатилъ экипажъ._ (Современникъ, 1864)

Comment: Второе предложение не подходит - там накрыто на стол (нужно без стола). Первое предложение мне кажется стилизованным под старину, так сейчас не говорят, да и стол какой-никакой всё-таки упоминается. А в заданном тексте сразу не поймешь, что там НАКРЫТО-ПОКРЫТО, надо тогда предложение править (мне так кажется). Буду категорически ПРОТИВ, пока не увижу это "накрыто" в современной художественной литературе (не в исторических романах).

Comment: Не жалую современных литераторов с журналистами, и начну с классики. _На стол**е** [где?] было еще не совсем накрыто._ (Достоевский, "Записки из подполья") Когда _**всё** было накрыто_ и кипящий самовар запел в центре стола, подпоручик молча указал на дверь..._ (Б. Васильев, "Были и небыли", сер. Русская классика, Вагриус, 2005)

Comment: Но вот и _они:_ _Там все уже было накрыто._ (Ф. Углов, "В плену иллюзий", Молодая гвардия, 1985) _Собственно говоря, там всё уже было накрыто и готово._ (Дарья Калинина, "Бабы Али-Бабы", Эксмо-пресс, 2011) _И он не ударил в грязь лицом: накрыто все было по высшему разряду._ (Е. Сухов, "Сходняк", 2017) _... нас сразу же повели в заводскую столовую, где уже было все накрыто на сорок персон._ (Самодеятельный театр, 1978)

Comment: А где безличная форма, у вас же  "всё накрыто" (двусоставное предложение), а в тексте "тут было тщательно накрыто".  Нельзя ли всё-таки безличную форму...плиз.

Comment: "Всё" в таких выражениях не играет роли подлежащего (не означает накрытости всего годного плоского) и имеет смысл готовности (полностью, окончательно; у Достоевского наоборот: "не совсем");  это "всё" ничему не подвергнуто, оно лишь описывает результат и легко отбрасывается, переставляется ("уже было всё накрыто по высшему разряду") - есть множество и таких примеров. _На столе уже было накрыто холодными закусками и выпивкой._ (А. Пенза, "Возвращение домой", 2017) _Юлия возвращалась домой лишь завтра, потому накрыто было традиционно – по высшему разряду._ (Н. Леонов, "Шакалы", 2007)

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ваши труды, надеюсь наш редактор вами очень доволен, но меня Вы окончательно не убедили. "Всё" явно является подлежащим, здесь важна не семантика, а грамматика. Столы в примерах мелькают часто, предложения  могут быть неполными, без контекста не определишь. Я же возражаю против вполне конкретного предложения: Тут было тщательно накрыто. Замените хотя бы  "тут" на "всё". В приведенном контексте  "не читается" и сразу не понимается это предложение. Коридор, в нем столы и стулья, что и чем там накрыто? В качестве последнего довода  - ну неужели не видно? Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: А "здесь было тщательно прибрано" тоже плохо? Разве возникают вопросы "что, чем и кем было прибрано"?

Comment: Совсем разные примеры. ПРИБРАТЬ,  1. что. Разг. Привести в порядок, произвести уборку. П. комнату, постель. П. в квартире, на столе. Как мы видим, безличная форма (прибрано в квартире) обозначена в словаре. Сравним. НАКРЫТЬ,  1. Покрыть, прикрыть чем-л. сверху. Н. стол скатертью. И т.д. И только после трех значений обозначено словосочетание: Накрыть на стол. Приготовить стол для еды, застлав его скатертью, расставив приборы.  А вы это сочетание еще и стола лишили.

Comment: Да не нужен там стол, уже давно "накрывают на столько-то персон (или кому-то в каком-то помещении)", не подразумевая, что конкретно накрывают (стол, много столов, поляну или подоконник) и есть ли покров.

Comment: Alex_ander, да я не против, пусть накрывают. Остановимся на том, что мне НЕ НРАВИТСЯ это конкретное предложение. Почему - я объяснила, но меня никто не поддержал. Возможно, все правы, а я нет. Но я бы написала "накрыто" курсивом, который обозначил бы более свободное обращение с этим словосочетанием, чем это дозволено в словаре (мне очень нравится курсив, он так красиво и современно смотрится). Как знать, вдруг меня автор УСЛЫШИТ, а вот вас всех - нет.  Хотя вряд ли, конечно.